# Flutter: Widget with Wordpress API

Tags: dart, flutter, wordpress-rest-api

i want to create a Flutter app that fetches the latest posts from Wordpress (WP REST API) but i get a red screen on my device after running it. I'm not very experienced in Flutter yet so i hope i can get some help here. As i can't post the whole Error log here because i need to write more i picked these 2 lines out that could be interesting:

I/flutter (18219): The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild layout delegate forgot to lay out the following children:
I/flutter (18219):   _ScaffoldSlot.body: RenderPhysicalModel#e87c7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

home_widget.dart

```
import 'news_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'platzhalter_widget.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
   NewsWidget(),
   PlatzhalterWidget(Colors.deepOrange),
   PlatzhalterWidget(Colors.green),
 ];
```

news_widget.dart

```
class NewsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return NewsWidgetState();
  }
}

class NewsWidgetState extends State<NewsWidget> {
  // Base URL for the wordpress site
  final String url = "https://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.com/";

  //api
  final String api = "wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed";
  // Empty list for the posts

  List posts;

  // Function to fetch list of posts
  Future<String> getPosts() async {
    var res = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url + api),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    // fill the post list with results and update state
    setState(() {
      var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
      posts = resBody;
    });

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getPosts();
  }
```

Comment: Can you link to the location of your PlatzhalterWidget?

Comment: /lib/platzhalter_widget.dart

Comment: thought it was a package, do you mind updating your question with the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue can happen when changing a widget from stateless to stateful or the other way around and trying to reload after. I suggest restarting the app, it seems to solve the issue. Or you can try cold restarting (stop the app and start again).